# How to increase number of rows in UITableview at run time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know whether there is any way to increase the number of rows of a `UITableview` without calling reload? I dont want to reload entire table just add new rows at run time.
i Know how to insert new row and updates but the row count increases only after calling reload on the `UITableView` object is there a way out?

Comment: Any mutable cousin of UITable view or any library imaitating smthng similar?

Comment: do you mean you need to append it as u scroll down to bottom of the tableview?

Comment: If you try to do it in runtime, there is chance for UI to get stuck and so its not a good practice.I too faced such a similar situation once, so based on my experience, I would suggest that the best way is to fetch the data asynchronously in background during runtime and call a delegate on completion to reload the tableview , in the mean time add an activity indicator , I think this is a clean method.

Comment: I am dooing that but i am not getting all data in one web service

Comment: Thats not a problem! You dont need to fetch everything altogether, I told you na, just fetch it asynchronously throughout your runtime,and reload when each one gets finished

Comment: i'm lookign for a solution to this, were you able to solve this?  I have dynamic height rows and resizing causes the scrollbar to jump so if I increase the numbe of rows, there will be less jumping

Comment: @TWilly I just inserted rows at index under begin and end updates.in ios 9 it causes jump so had to set content offset.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];    
//put these indexpaths in a NSArray

[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I wouldn't worry too much about calling `reloadData` on a table view. `UITableView` is actually very efficient at displaying and reusing cells.

Just make sure you're correctly creating cells (using a `cell reuse identifier`), or else you could be (or rather, are likely) leaking memory, and this **isn't** efficient (it is processor expense to constantly create new cells, instead of reusing them).

If you are new to using `UITableView`, or need a refresher on using them, here's a tutorial on it:

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/

There's also a ton of good tutorials (you can likely just click any at random, and it will have an example somewhere within it using `UITableView`) on Ray Wenderlich's site:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/